# Please enable the AMScd package by default

Tags: feature-request, mathjax

We can draw diagrams using the AMScd package, and works quite nicely (see Math.SE for a working proof).

However, on MathOverflow the package seems to be disabled by default, so if a user wants to use it they have to load it explicitly using `\require{AMScd}`.

I see little point in not having this loaded automatically, and I think that this should be corrected.

Comment: The phrasing of the title and the tag [meta-tag:feature-request] do not work well together, IMO. (The title would be good for a [meta-tag:discussion] or [meta-tag:support]  though.)

Comment: quid, is it better now?

Comment: Yes, I think so. Thanks.

Comment: Could you link to an example of drawing diagrams using the AMScd package? I am just curious...

Comment: @Joseph: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9387/mathjax-2-2-beta/9401#9401

Comment: Ah--Thanks!${}{}$

Comment: Looking into this.

Comment: @Tim: Thank you. The same goes for MSE, actually. I found out that the package is no longer automatically loaded there as well.